# C++ XML parsing library for large files with low RAM consumpion

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, static-libraries

Which XML library for C++ uses the lowest amount of RAM while parsing e. g. 300M file? Ideally the choice should be restricted to one of RapidXml, Pugixml, Libxml, Boost, TinyXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't clarified your complete requirements. There are 2 commonly used xml parsing models: DOM and SAX. In DOM the entire file is parsed into memory as a tree where as SAX is more of a event driven library. If you are

1. not planning to modify the XML & just consume it and
2. concerned about RAM usage

then using SAX model will be optimum. I will be surprised if half decent implementation of SAX is memory intensive. Also look at this post: [Light weight C++ SAX XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684440/light-weight-c-sax-xml-parser)

Comment: Good, go for SAX library. I have used Xerces C++ DOM parser a lot. Works well. Xerces also has a SAX parser which you should look into.

Comment: if I chose one of those mentioned in my Q for performance reasons, which one is most RAM efficient?